# VisualStateManager for UI Responsive is not working in UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

in my uwp desktop application. I have crated one user control for header. for responsive UI i am using the VisualStateManager But its not working when i am resizing the page.i want to keep moving right hand side controls to left when i am resizing the page.this code working in some situation.

[image]

I want to reduce the middle blank space size when i am resize the window. 
 thanks in advance :)

```
<UserControl
x:Class="UWPUIResponsive.UC_Header"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignWidth="400" Height="50" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0 0 1 1"  >

<Grid >
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualState>

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <!--<Setter Target = "Parent.Orientation" Value = "Horizontal" />-->
                    <Setter Target = "CThree.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CFour.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CTen.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CThree.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CEight.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CSix.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "1250" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <!--<Setter Target = "Parent.Orientation" Value = "Horizontal" />-->
                    <Setter Target = "Cone.Width" Value = "10*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CTwo.Width" Value = "60*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CThree.Width" Value = "250*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CFour.Width" Value = "16*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CFive.Width" Value = "*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CSix.Width" Value = "23*" />

                    <Setter Target = "CSeven.Width" Value = "" />
                    <Setter Target = "CEight.Width" Value = "8*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CNine.Width" Value = "" />
                    <Setter Target = "CTen.Width" Value = "4*" />
                    <Setter Target = "CEleven.Width" Value = "25*" />


                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>


            <VisualState>

                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                     <!--VisualState to be triggered when window 
                 width is >=720 effective pixels.--> 
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth = "500" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>

                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <!--<Setter Target = "Parent.Orientation" Value = "Horizontal" />-->
                    <Setter Target = "Cone.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CTwo.Width" Value = "Auto" />

                    <Setter Target = "CThree.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CFour.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CFive.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CSix.Width" Value = "Auto" />

                    <Setter Target = "CSeven.Width" Value = "" />
                    <Setter Target = "CEight.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CNine.Width" Value = "" />
                    <Setter Target = "CTen.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                    <Setter Target = "CEleven.Width" Value = "Auto" />
                </VisualState.Setters>

            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid Name="Parent"  BorderBrush="Silver"  BorderThickness="0 0 1 1"  >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Cone" Width="10*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CTwo" Width="60*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CThree" Width="250*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CFour" Width="16*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CFive" Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CSix" Width="23*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CSeven"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CEight"  Width="8*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CNine"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CTen" Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="CEleven" Width="25*"/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Image  Source="Application_Images\circle.png"  Stretch="Uniform"       Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,9,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Image Source="Application_Images\circle.png"  Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.057,0.714" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,3,0,2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <TextBlock  FontSize="14" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TBUserName" Foreground="#27aae1" TextAlignment="right" Grid.Column="5" Margin="3,3,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text=" Admin" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TBRole" Foreground="#414042" TextAlignment="right" Grid.Column="5" Margin="3,1,0,8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>

    <Button  Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="9" Margin="0,0,3,6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.Row="4" Width="6" Height="5">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Button.RenderTransform>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Stretch="Fill"     Source="Application_Images\circle.png"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <!--<Image Source="dropdown.png" Margin="9,8,0,4"  />-->
        <Button.Flyout>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="settings">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text = "Profile" />
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text = "Sign Out"  />
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
    <Image ToolTipService.ToolTip="Dashboard" Source="Application_Images\circle.png" Stretch="Uniform"   Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"  Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <StackPanel Background="#E1E1E1" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,13" Width="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Row="2"    />

</Grid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complex Grid layout can be confusing. I simplified your layout based on the actual display of the application, and narrowed the distance between the logo and the account.

```xml
<Grid>
   <!-- <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TitleColumn.Width" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="HolderColumn1.Width" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Target="HolderColumn2.Width" Value="Auto"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="750" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="TitleColumn.Width" Value="20*"/>
                    <Setter Target="HolderColumn1.Width" Value="*"/>
                    <Setter Target="HolderColumn2.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>-->

    <Grid x:Name="p" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="HolderColumn1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" x:Name="TitleColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="AccountColumn"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="HolderColumn2"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="Application_Images\circle.png"  Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,9,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Image ToolTipService.ToolTip="Dashboard" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Application_Images\circle.png" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Margin="15,0,0,0" Padding="15,0,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock  FontSize="14" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TBUserName" Foreground="#27aae1" TextAlignment="right" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text="Admin" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="TBRole" Foreground="#414042" TextAlignment="right" >
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Application_Images\circle.png" Height="30" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.057,0.714" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,3,10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Button  Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,3,6" Height="5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="Application_Images\circle.png"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                    <Button.Flyout>
                        <MenuFlyout x:Name="settings">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text = "Profile" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text = "Sign Out"  />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </Button.Flyout>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>    
</Grid>
```

Here is what display:

[image: 82dfd363-fb2f-4bc2-9e2f-cb44b7a7d01b.png]

### Update

In the Grid row/column definition, `*` represents the space left. However, if the definitions have many `*`, it means that these spaces are allocated proportionally. such as:

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Means the second column is twice the width of the first column.

And `Auto` means that the width or height changes as the content changes.

In the layout I gave, the ratio of `TitleColumn` to `HolderColumn` is 20:1, which is equivalent to a dynamic **Padding**, which is not functional. You can also replace it with Grid's Padding.

At this time, the width of the `AccountColumn` is determined by the content, and all the remaining space is occupied by the `TitleColumn`. As the width of the window changes, the distance between the controls changes proportionally. This is the reason for self-adaptation.

Best regards.

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply it works but i want to keep my R.H.S side always right side when i am resizing the page at run time.

Comment: That is not difficult, just remove the VisualStateManager. Your responsiveness will be implemented with the Grid column width `*`

Comment: it works perfectly thank you for your time and reply :) have a great day..

Comment: would you please explain me in simple way 1. difference between *,2*,23,Auto  ?2.when we will use the visualstatemanager ?

Comment: Hi, Can you explain what `2,23,Auto` means? There are many usage scenarios for `VisualStateManager`, such as your title bar being displayed horizontally on a wide screen and vertically on a narrow screen. But as far as the layout you provide is concerned, it seems that you can use the adaptive properties of Grid to meet your needs. If you think that this layout can't meet your needs, can you provide more explanation?

Comment: no it works perfectly . i want to know diffffrence between `*`,2`*`,2 and Auto ? and you define which grid column to `*`?

Comment: Hi, I update my answer to explain the layout. You can confirm the child elements by the name of the column.