# How to disable scaling for UWP apps

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm designing uwp apps. My pc resolution is 1920 x 1080, 100% scale. All the elements are layout normal.
But when running app on a screen 1920 x 1080, 125% scale, the elements are not in the right place and all are 1.25x bigger.

So how to disable scale under all resolutions, or is there any solutions?

Comment: you need to design each screen in responsive manner by setting each controls horizontal and vertical properties to stretch that's the only solution for it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57250223/11362349) refer the link for more details. you must need to design your UI responsive.

Comment: If a user's screen is 1920x1080, 100% scale, app shows normal. What happens if he turns to 200% scale? I think it's a mess under 200%, cause all the margins are scaled bigger. How to handle this? I know one way is use Grid row and column, but they don't layout my elements on the right position as designed.

Comment: suppose you have a button on left side and you want this button looks same in same resolution then remove  * from the grid row and column Definition then see the output it looks same for all resolution.

Comment: This feels like 'how do I disable user'. You can't disable the user, user has asked the operating system to have bigger controls (possibly he has eyesight problems) and it is yours to meet user expectations and keep the app running.

Comment: have you tried my solution ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving you the simple example in which i am showing two buttons and one grid you can run this on any resolution the left and right hand side button always keep in same position and grid will change accordingly resolution size

```
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="169*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="113*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,55,10,40" />
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,55,10,40" Grid.Column="2" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    </Gid>
```

your code sample

```
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="945"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="945"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Color"
            Margin="117, 84, 0, 0"
            FontSize="48"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Red" Width="500" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="445 30 0 0"
                />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Yellow" Width="500" Height="80" 
                Margin="0 30 445 0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>


        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Margin="84 40 84 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, I tried your sample, it works, because you don't specify button width. you can try my code https://gist.github.com/hupo376787/cfeb0fad50f20f59bfdd4b34ce42bce4

Comment: why you want the 445 margin in left and right for respective buttons set button margin to 0 and set horizontal and vertical alignment to Center it will not overlaps the buttons

Comment: As ui designs, the button has to be in that place in 1920x1080.

Comment: OK, I tried. Maybe I should convince ui to redesign and consider scale factor in it? Is there any open source project which contains both ui and xaml, so we can learn from it.

Comment: sorry i don't have any idea the open source project :) i think ui designer should provide the design for each resolution